# How to add a jquery accordion dynamically to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a div `<div id="detailTable" width="100%">` in which i append different widgets sometimes other content, so in order for the jsp page not to look cumbersome, i am removing any existing elements inside `detailTable` and adding  contents on some click. Now I want to add a jQuery accordion but it does not seem to work. Please provide a solution in this context. Thanks

Here is what i am doing to remove and add accordion in `detailTable` on button click

```
$('#detailTable').empty();
$('<div>')
.attr('id','healthCheckSpan')
.html('<div class="titleBlue">Health Check Summary</div>'+
        '<table style="border:#2F5882 1px solid;width:100%;"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">'+
            '<thead>'+
                '<tr style="color :#FFFFFF;background-color: #8EA4BB">'+
                    '<th width="10%" align="center"><b>Recommendations</b></th>'+
                '</tr>'+
            '</thead>'+
            '<tbody >'+
                '<tr style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #EDF1F5">'+
                    '<td align="left" width="10%">'+
                        '<span id="recommendations">'+

'<div id="hcAccordion">'+
'<h3><a href="#">Error</a></h3>'+
'<div><p id="errorhc">ERROR'+
'</p></div>'+

'<h3><a href="#">Warning</a></h3>'+
'<div><p id="warninghc">WARNING'+
'</p></div>'+

'<h3><a href="#">Info</a></h3>'+
'<div><p id="infohc">INFO'+
'</p></div>'+
'</div>'+

'<script>$(document).ready(function(){'+
'$(function() {     $( "#hcAccordion" ).accordion();    });'+
'});</script>'+     
                        '</span>'+
                    '</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
            '</tbody>'+
        '</table>'+
    '</div>')       
.appendTo('#detailTable');
```

My screenshot, here i just get a supposed to be accordion but no effects at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you should remove that ugly `html('....blabla....');` it's terrible...

put that in your normal html, and hide it, then copy it using `clone()`,

**jquery**

```
 var html_data = $('#hidden_wrapper').clone().html();
    $('#detailTable').empty();
    $('<div>')
    .attr('id','healthCheckSpan')
    .html(html_data)       
    .appendTo('#detailTable').delay(1).queue(function(){
        $( "#hcAccordion" ).accordion();
         // now do not use ID as this would change if there are multiple ones... use classes .hcAccordion unless it is once.
    });
```

**html**

```
<div id="hidden_wrapper">... accordion goes here...</div>
```

Comment: @val, how do u handle id's inside html which are being cloned? Like "#hcAccordion"?? Also if u use classes, accordian will animate both and appear on screen when animation stops. Better keep html_data as string outside the function

Comment: thats what the comment explains that id's are not good and he/she should use classes , html(html_data) will carry the structure for the accordion...

Comment: @Val: hcAccordion will only be once, also did you notice `$('#detailTable').empty();` because I am using it to remove all the contents so i can't add `hidden_wrapper` in my html.. am i correct?

Comment: @Val: I did as you asked, but does not produce any result, please suggest something. Thanks

Comment: @Val: but the link does not have an Accordion. it is still without any effects

Comment: its because i don't know how to add accordion on js fiddle as it's a ui, lol but try it on your script it should work

Comment: @Val: I am really getting annoying asking so many qns.. sorry for that, I tried and I have added `jquery.dimensions.js`, `jquery.easing.js` and `jquery.dimensions.js` libraries and did as you explained, but nothing seems to work :( please help

Comment: @Val: I added the jQuery accordion library link in [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7J6rR/1/)

Comment: Ok this is how you do it, you put everything in one function, make sure you trigger it at the right time, http://jsfiddle.net/7J6rR/3/ for example `$(document).ready(function(){   my_personal_foo();  })` or on a button like on the example, and it should work fine,

Comment: @Val: Thanks, i'll try to figure out :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7J6rR/4/  ... there this is more promising, btw u had the wrong file there for the resource,

Comment: @Val: thanks for your support, i used your technique and managed to add effects to the accordion. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your accordion and then just append or delete divs as you need to.  So take
    '$(document).ready(function(){'+
        '$(function() {     $( "#hcAccordion" ).accordion();    });'+
    '});'
out of your dynamic HTML and have it run as the page loads.

Comment: this `detailTable` is the container that contains different type of contents, so its not always an accordion, that means i cannot create accordion 1t and then append others inside it.. please suggest something in this context. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Following code already added but js is not excuted as it is supposed to load on ready, which is i guess already raised.

Get rid of this code

```
    '<script>$(document).ready(function(){'+
'$(function() {     $( "#hcAccordion" ).accordion();    });'+
'});</script>'+
```

and call `$( "#hcAccordion" ).accordion();` after ur append code

Comment: I thought so, but i get this error in  Firefox error console. Error: $("#hcAccordion").accordion is not a function
Source File: http://in164263:10070/csm/showResult.action
Line: 0

Comment: delay the code as suggested by val. Ensure accordian js is loaded. You can load the JS dynamically too. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: i did as u asked `.appendTo('#detailTable').delay(1).queue(function(){
        $( "#hcAccordion" ).accordion();       
   });`, still no luck, instead IE8 gives me this error `object dosen't support this property or method`